# Not able to start kibana on mac. Setup lifecycle of "apm" plugin wasn't completed in 30sec

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

[fatal][root] Error: Setup lifecycle of "apm" plugin wasn't completed in 30sec. Consider disabling the plugin and re-start.
    at Timeout.setTimeout (/usr/local/Cellar/kibana-full/7.6.0/libexec/src/core/utils/promise.js:31:90)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:436:11)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:300:5)
    at listOnTimeout (timers.js:263:5)
    at Timer.processTimers (timers.js:223:10)

**FATAL  Error: Setup lifecycle of "apm" plugin wasn't completed in 30sec. Consider disabling the plugin and re-start.**

Kibana version-7.6

Comment: I found that using version 7.5.2 does not cause this problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting your ES cluster, have been success in get Kibana startup thereafter, might be some connection issue b/w the ES & Kibana which is preventing the plugin to install.